# Having issues with user input and scanner

Tags: java

Quick overview:

Im doing a basic program that asks the user how many doors they want their "dream car" to have.

```
public static void main(String [ ] args){


CarSim carSimUser1 = new CarSim();



System.out.println("Hello, and welcome to Car Matcher!");

Scanner scanName = new Scanner(System.in);    // user input for name

System.out.println("What's your name?");
String userName = scanName.nextLine();

System.out.println("Hello " + userName);
System.out.println("So you are looking for a new Car?");
System.out.println("Would you like 4 door sedan");
System.out.println("Or a two door coupe?");
System.out.println("Enter a number only!");



Scanner scanDoor = new Scanner(System.in);   // user input for number of doors
int numbOfDoor = scanDoor.nextInt();



while(numbOfDoor <= 4){

    if(numbOfDoor == 4){
        System.out.println("Okay, so you want " + numbOfDoor);

    }


    else if(numbOfDoor == 2){

        System.out.println("Okay, so you want " + numbOfDoor);
break;  
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("Select either 2 or 4 doors!");
        break;
}

enter code here
```

When I prompt the user how many doors they want their car to have, they only have two choices, to enter the number 2 or 4. But if they enter any other number they cannot go back and enter either 2 or 4. How can I get my program to allow the user to enter the correct number if their input wasnt 2 or 4 in the first place?

Sorry if vague, i dont have a text book because I am not a CS student currently, learning on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possibility. Note that numbOfDoor is set to 0, the test checking that it isn't one of the acceptable values, and that the nextInt *is inside the loop*. It's not necessary to have break statements.

```
int numbOfDoor = 0;
while(numbOfDoor != 2 && numbOfDoor != 4){
    numbOfDoor = scanDoor.nextInt();
    if(numbOfDoor == 4){
         System.out.println("Okay, so you want " + numbOfDoor);
    } else if(numbOfDoor == 2){
        System.out.println("Okay, so you want " + numbOfDoor);    
    } else{
        System.out.println("Select either 2 or 4 doors!");
    }
}
```

You might also use

```
int numbOfDoor = 0;
while( true ){
    numbOfDoor = scanDoor.nextInt();
    if(numbOfDoor == 4){
         System.out.println("Okay, so you want " + numbOfDoor);
         break;
    }
    // More if + println + break
}
```

Here you need break statements.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to the question can as follows. It is not the most elegant solution but it is nearly word for word from your code. A good trick to learn from this example would be to use while loops around your inputs so that you can increase the robustness of your code.

```
int numbOfDoor = scanDoor.nextInt();
    while (numbOfDoor != 2 || numbOfDoor != 4)
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid choice, try again: ");
        numbOfDoor = scanDoor.nextInt();

        if (numbOfDoor == 2 || numbOfDoor == 4)
            break;

    }

    if(numbOfDoor == 4)
    {
       System.out.println("Okay, so you want " + numbOfDoor);

    }


    else if(numbOfDoor == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Okay, so you want " + numbOfDoor); 
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Select either 2 or 4 doors!");

    }
scanDoor.close()
```